# Unresolved external symbols (LNK2001) are clearly found in .obj file

Tags: c++, c++11, linker-errors, unresolved-external, lnk2001

Let's say there is `class A` and `class B`.
`Class A` has a number of of private static data members and implements some getters for those, so they can be read but not written from the outside.
`Class B` includes `A.h`, but does not make any calls to `A`'s methods.
Note that these classes are both part of their own dlls respectively. `Class A` is, as a whole, labelled `__declspec(dllexport)` so it should be visible.

Building this in Visual Studio is no problem.
My Company needs me to build with an in-house script too, but that doesnt work.
I think that script is based around gms-make but I'm not sure. I also don't know what compiler or linker is being used there.

Throwing this thing into our script gives me `LNK2001: unresolved external symbol` in `B.obj`.
The symbols that cannot be resolved are the private static data members inside `class A`.
When I look at the symbols of `B.obj` using DUMPBIN, I can find all of these symbols.
(I'm not  quite sure whether they're supposed to be there or not, but they are.)

What's more is that another class, `class C`, living in yet another dll, can import all the information needed from `class A`. Both in VS and in our script, even though the setup is the same as with `class B`.

Removing `#include "A.h"` from `B.cpp`makes the linker happy again, but I need to use that include there.

I'm told the problem is not with the linker but with my code, so what could I be doing wrong?
Also why does `class B` try to resolve symbols to private members of another class? Shouldn't those be invisible?

Comment: Without an [mcve] this is impossible to say for sure, but my magic ball tells me that your `__declspec` macro that conditionally marks A's methods as `dllexport` when building `A`'s project and as `dllimport` otherwise is not being defined properly in your new make script.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the time to work up a reprex, especially given the fact that I can't give away our build script.
On another note: Your magic ball might be on to something there. Thanks for the hint.